# Calling WCF Rest service by POST from angular 5 service

Tags: angular, rest, wcf, post

I'm trying to POST WCF rest service from angular service, but it doesn't work and I've no idea what's wrong. My GET service is working and I'm able to receive List, then I do some Star mofification and I'm trying to POST it back to WCF server. Unfortunately my Save method is no called and I can't see any errors on console.

My WCF service looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       UriTemplate = "GetAllStars")]
    List<Star> GetAllStars();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   UriTemplate = "Save")]
Star Save(Star st);

[DataContract]
public class Star
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
...}
```

web.xml configuration

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="SharksHunter.Service.Net.CORSEnablingBehavior, SharksHunter.Service.Net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="SharksHunter.Service.Net.StarService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="SharksHunter.Service.Net.IStarService" 
  />
  <endpoint   name="mexHttpBinding"
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"
              />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
      <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>    

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and my angular service is like this:

```
private starsUrlGet = 'http://localhost:39958/StarService.svc/GetAllStars';  

private starsUrlPost = 'http://localhost:39958/StarService.svc/Save';  


....
this.http.get<Star[]>(this.starsUrlGet); -> this is WORKING


public saveStar(st: Star) 
{

this.http.post<Star>(this.starsUrlPost, st); -> this is not WORKING
}
```

In code above, GET is working perfectly, but POST in not called at all, why? 
Thanks a lot